# Java Spark - Data Encryption

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a Java library that can encrypt the data.

I want to encrypt certain columns of the spark dataframe with that encryption library and send it to some API.

I have tried foreachPartition to iterate the column values row by row and encrypt it.

```
df.select(col).javaRDD().foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<Row>>() {
        static final long serialVersionUID = 8L;

        @Override
        public void call(Iterator<Row> t) throws Exception {
                    while (t.hasNext()) {

            try {
                Row row = t.next();
                PIDataEncryptionProvider.encrypt(row.mkString());


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }


        }
    });
```

Now I have to replace the existing column values with this encrypted values in certain columns that I have given for select transformation.

Dropping the existing column and adding the new column with same name, then add the encrypted values to the newly added column.If this is the way, How efficiently can we do this?

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the PIDataEncryptionProvider class with me ?